# Method is clearly defined but VS complains that it isn't

Tags: c#

I have a factory method in a normally instantiable class.  Intellisense shows that it is valid (i.e. it shows up when I type "Entity.") and shows the proper tooltip before building.  When I build, however, I get this error:

> 'EvergreenEngine.Entity' does not contain a definition for 'Load'

What is going on here?
This is my class.  Ignore that the method doesn't actually do anything for now.

```
// Represents an object in the game world
public class Entity
{
    // Snip other methods and stuff

    // Loads an entity from an XML file
    public static Entity Load(string filename) // Apparently undefined
    {
        Entity newEntity = new Entity();

        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
        while(reader.Read())
        {
            Logger.Log(reader.Name);
        }

        return newEntity;
    }
}
```

**SOLVED IT**

Apparently, I had it compiling to x86 (I'm on a 64bit machine) and VS didn't like that.  Very odd.

Comment: How is this class referenced? Is it in a separate project within the same solution or in a library that you build previously?

Comment: It's in a separate project (class library) within the solution.  Everything works except for static methods within the class.

Comment: We've had this happen with a particular project in our solution from time to time. The IDE ties up the reference somehow. The solution for us was to remove the project reference, check it in, clean the solution, build unsuccessfully, then re-add the project reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, I had it compiling to x86 (I'm on a 64bit machine) and VS didn't like that. Very odd.

It worked when I set it back to Mixed Platforms.

Comment: was the class library and the project using it set to different platforms (curious as to why that would be a issue otherwise)

Comment: This is probably not the correct explanation.  Switch your failing project back to the Client profile to repro the problem.